# link to home directory in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, directory

For the website I am developing, there is to be a link to Home directory in the master file's footer. Thus, I 
 used `<a href="/">Home</a>` but it doesn't work. In fact it needs the name of my site, say 
 `<a href="/MySite"></a>` to load the Default.aspx of the home directory. 
I am looking for a way to specify the URL independent from whatever the name of my site is (here Mysite), because I fear using site name might raise issues in future if I decide to rename the home folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try that:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/">Home</asp:HyperLink>
```

Home page name: Default.aspx