# How to manipulate a url to access a parent directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an asp.net web application that is being hosted on an internal network. In my testing environment of course it gets hosted out on localhost:01010/Views/page.aspx. now whenever I take it live the Url changes to server_name/folder 1/folder 2/views/page.aspx. what I am trying to do is get a new page to open up as server_name/folder 1/folder 2/Uploaded_Images/randomimage.png. Now I Can get the url, but as soon as I do a single ".Remove(url.lastindexof("/")+1)" it returns "server_name/folder 1/folder 2/Views". The I perform my second "`.Remove(url.lastindexof("/")+1)`"
and the it only returns "server_name/". I am ripping my hair out at this one and am hoping somewhere in the world a .net developer already has this built in. Appreciate all the help.

Also just to specify this is webforms and not mvc. also there is no ajax or page manipulation going on except for a response.write to open the new page.

Comment: Instead of navigating up and over and down, start at the root (known as `~`).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034626/link-to-home-directory-in-asp-net

Comment: don't use whitespaces in on-line folder names

Comment: It's most likely just a minor mistake in the string handling. Recreate the problem in a stand-alone console app and post it here and someone will solve it (but more likely you'll solve it yourself in the process!)

Comment: @Flydog57 I have tried that, it simply returns "server_name/" and then I would have to hard code the values down the road which doesnt make the application super easy to migrate from server to server.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the static methods in the `System.IO.Path` class.  I thing they work with URLs as well as file/folder path names.

Comment: @Flydog57 I have, but they have this weird thing where they practically give access to the servers entire file directory. which is kind of making me weary in terms of security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `+1`, this works:

```
var url = "server_name/folder 1/folder 2/views/page.aspx";
url = url.Remove(url.LastIndexOf("/"));
url = url.Remove(url.LastIndexOf("/"));
```

Or you could do it like this:

```
var parts = url.Split('/');
var newPath = string.Join("/", parts.Take(3));
```

Comment: This was it. gosh you are my hero good sir. Thanks everybody for their time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about URL's used as links to parts of your site and not physical paths on the file system.

In most cases, you should be able to use methods that construct paths on the fly. For example, in any of your .aspx files (or .aspx.cs files), you can use the [`ResolveUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl) method, like this:

```
<a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Views/page.aspx")%>">Some link</a>
```

If there are any places where you need the full URL including the domain (like for email notifications or something like that) then what I have done is keep a static variable accessible to my whole application that gets set the first time `Application_BeginRequest` runs:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (SiteRoot == null) {
        SiteRoot = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +
            (VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~") == "/" ? "" : VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~"));
    }
}
```

That will pull the full URL from the `Request` details (the URL that the user used to access your site), without any trailing slash.